# WindowEvent without specification?

Tags: java, user-interface, javafx

```
BetrachterFXMLController controller = loader<BetrachterFXMLController>getController();
EventHandler<WindowEvent> h;
        h = (WindowEvent event) -> {
            event.consume();
            controller.end();
        };
```

I just see this type of EventHandler for the first time. What it is supposed to do is, that it should tell the controller to close the program (end() simply calls Platform.exit) when the X at the top is clicked. This is due to the fact that this GUI has multiple windows and all windows should be closed when the main window is closed.

What I don't get is why the EventHandler simply waits for a random(?) WindowEvent. Doesn't it has to be specified which WindowEvent it handles?

Comment: You specify the type of event it handles when you register it, with `someWindow.addEventHandler(...);`, or `someWindow.setOnXXX(...)`.

Comment: You mean something like that: stage.setOnCloseRequest(h); ?

Comment: Yes, exactly. So that only registers it for close requests. Similarly, `someWindow.addEventHandler(WindowEvent.WINDOW_CLOSE_REQUEST, h);`.